# How can I test list of regular expressions, if they are all valid (line by line)?

Tags: regex

For our anti-spam program we have a list of regular expressions. For incoming emails, each regex is tested against subject and body. At the moment, this list contains about 200 lines, each line consists of exactly one regex.

I suspect that there is an invalid regex in the list somewhere.

Now, I'm looking for a way, how I can test, if each line contains a valid regex and to get notified for every line, where the regex is invalid.

With all the tools and websites to test, if a string matches one regex, I couldn't find, what I'm searching for.

Do you know such a way?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What programming language are you using?

Comment: For each line, `try` evaluating the regex using your language's native parser, then `catch` any errors and log accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm more of an admin guy lately, I first thought of something "ready to use". ;-)

Since I installed Python recently and I remembered a presentation, where ChatGPT generated some code, I'd decided to give it a try. And it worked:

```
import re

def main():
    print("Please enter a multi-line string (Enter 'EOF' to finish):")
    input_lines = []
    while True:
        line = input()
        if line == "EOF":
            break
        input_lines.append(line)

    valid_count = 0
    invalid_count = 0

    for i, line in enumerate(input_lines, start=1):
        try:
            re.compile(line)
            valid_count += 1
        except re.error:
            invalid_count += 1
            print(f"Line {i}: Invalid regular expression - {line}")

    print("\nSummary:")
    print(f"Valid regular expressions: {valid_count}")
    print(f"Invalid regular expressions: {invalid_count}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

First prompt:

> Write a Python program, which will do the following tasks:
>
> 1. Let me input a multi-line string.
> 2. For each line:
>    a. Test, if the line contains a valid regular expression.
>    b. If the regular expression is invalid, output the number of the line and the content of the line.

Second prompt:

> modify program that it summarizes the number of valid and invalid lines at the end